# how to specify color of contour in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, contour

I think it is not a fresh question but I didn't find a concrete solution or the solution I found so far doesn't solve my problem. I am trying to plot a contour (not contourf) of specific level of some 3D data in matlab. I found some solution is trying to look for the patch object and define the facecolor from there for each contour line.

```
f=peaks(512)*10; 
[C,h] = contour(f, [-60 -30 -20 0 20 30 50 60]); 
colorbar;
Cld = get(h, 'children');
for j=1:length(Cld)
  if strcmp(get(Cld(j), 'Type'), 'patch')
    Iso = get(Cld(j), 'CData');
    if Iso==-60
      set(Cld(j), 'facecolor', [1 0 0]);
    elseif Iso==-30
      set(Cld(j), 'facecolor', [0 1 0]);
    elseif Iso==-20
      set(Cld(j), 'facecolor', [0 0 1]);
    elseif Iso==0
      set(Cld(j), 'facecolor', [0.5 0.3 0]);
    elseif Iso==20
      set(Cld(j), 'facecolor', [0.9 0 0.3]);
    elseif Iso==30
      set(Cld(j), 'facecolor', [0.8 0.7 0.1]);
    elseif Iso==50
      set(Cld(j), 'facecolor', [0.25 0.66 0.4]);
    elseif Iso==60
      set(Cld(j), 'facecolor', [0.5 0.1 0.3]);
    end
  end
end
```

This code plots the line not exactly on level -60 -30 -20 0 20 30 50 and 60 but something close as well. Secondly, it doesn't use the color I specify, it seems that it doesn't contain any patch objects from that handle.

updated: I find a way to do the trick

```
hold on; contour(f, [-60 -60], 'linewidth', 2, 'linecolor','m'); 
hold on; contour(f, [-30 -30], 'linewidth', 2, 'linecolor','c'); 
hold on; contour(f, [-20 -20], 'linewidth', 2, 'linecolor','y'); 
hold on; contour(f, [0 0], 'linewidth', 2, 'linecolor','k'); 
hold on; contour(f, [20 20], 'linewidth', 2, 'linecolor','b');
hold on; contour(f, [30 30], 'linewidth', 2, 'linecolor','g');
hold on; contour(f, [60 60], 'linewidth', 2, 'linecolor','r');
```

The color of lines changed, the level shown is as expected. But the colorbar doesn't change accordingly. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `contour` plot uses the current colormap of the figure to decide what color the contour lines are going to be. Rather than creating a bunch of separate `contour` objects (that are no longer tied to the colormap/colorbar as you've found) it is easier to construct a custom colormap to use that corresponds to the colors you want.

So for your example this colormap (based on your data above) would look something like this.

```
cmap = [1 0 1;  % magenta
        0 1 1;  % cyan
        1 1 0;  % yellow
        0 0 0;  % black
        0 0 1;  % blue
        0 1 0;  % green
        1 0 0]; % red
```

So now we can create a single `contour` plot for all levels that you want to display with some pseudo data just with the difference that we'll set the figure's colormap to be the custom one defined above.

```
data = rand(10);
data = (data - 0.5) * 225;

contourLevels = [-60 -30 -20 0 20 30 60];

figure();
contour(data, contourLevels, 'LineWidth', 2);

% Use the custom colormap
colormap(cmap);

colorbar()
set(gca, 'clim', [-60 60])
```

[image]

Now you have data colored the way that you want, but now your data is linked to the colorbar.